# Multiple Constructors without changing previous data

Tags: java, constructor

I am in an oop class that is being presented with java.
I understand the concept of instantiating an object and using multiple constructors with overloading. In my current assignment, however, I am required to have at least two constructors but my objects all require the same data. They are books, each with a name, title, and isbn. all String.

I can't overload the constructor if I have the same signature. I also can not chain the constructors because I am already calling the super constructor in the first line.

If I separate something, such as the name, then call one constructor for the title and isbn then a second constructor for the name of course I have constructed a new object, or overwritten the old one in this case.

I am at a loss of what to do, I was trying to search if there was a way to call a second constructor for the same object to send the missing pieces of information. but came up empty-handed. I could use a setter method, but that does not satisfy the multiple constructors requirements.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Code is much more conducive to assistance; but you will likely have to default a parameter within the constructor and add setters.  In second constructor you could do `this(name,title,"")` which invokes the first constructor with a default - but it seems a book without the defined values would be in error.  Often assignments don't stand up to reason but are meant to put you through syntactic gymanastics.

Comment: Not sure there would be a real need for it, but perhaps a copy constructor?

Comment: You could have a constructor which doesn't take the ISBN, for "old books pre dating ISBNs".

Answer (score 0):

> *I am required to have at least two constructors but my objects all require the same data. They are books, each with a name, title, and isbn. all String.*

Here is a starting point that provides a class with a single constructor, and members for name, title and isbn.

```
class Book {
    String name;
    String title;
    String isbn;

    public Book(String name, String title, String isbn) {
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}
```

> *If I separate something, such as the name, then call one constructor for the title and isbn then a second constructor for the name of course I have constructed a new object, or overwritten the old one in this case.*

I like the idea of separating out a field, such as name, like this:

```
public Book(String title, String isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

And then after you called that constructor, you could set the "name" value:

```
Book book1 = new Book("title1", "isbn1");
book1.name = "name1";
```

UPDATE: I missed this, that you cannot use a setter: "*I could use a setter method, but that does not satisfy the multiple constructors requirements.*"

Note that it's better to make name, title, and isbn all "private", and expose a getter to modify the value:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Another option for a second constructor could be to set a value for "name" with some placeholder ("NOT SET"):

```
public Book(String title, String isbn) {
    this.name = "NOT SET";
    this.title = title;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

Or rewrite that second constructor to call the first one:

```
public Book(String title, String isbn) {
    this("NOT SET", title, isbn);
}
```

Here's what it would look like if you had three constructors:

- one that takes "title" only (assume that's the bare minimum of what is known about a book),
- one that takes title + name (where "name" means the author?"), and
- one that takes all three: title, name and isbn.

```
public Book(String title) {
    this(title, "unknown", "unknown");
}

public Book(String title, String name) {
    this(title, name, "unknown");
}

public Book(String title, String name, String isbn) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

If either of the first two constructors is called, a default value "unknown" is used.